# Migration from Azure HDInsight to Amazon EMR?

Tags: azure, hadoop, amazon-web-services, azure-hdinsight

Need help from Big Data experts.

We have currently started building a product, which has Big Data requirements, and for which we have chosen Hadoop. We currently don't have a lot of experience with Big Data.

For our Cloud platform and Hadoop, we are trying to choose between Azure HDInsight and Amazon AWS EMR. Our product will be built using .Net and we are already using Azure for another existing product. We also have experience with AWS, though not on Hadoop as yet.

Now, we know that Azure is not as mature as EMR, and AWS would be a better bet, at least for the next couple of years. However it probably would be easier to develop on Azure with .Net, and also save some upfront costs as we are already using it.

So, we are thinking of building the beta version of the product on Azure, validate and benchmark the performance. Then as a backup plan, if required move to AWS and EMR for the final product.

My questions are - 
How difficult would it be to migrate from HDInsight to EMR? 
How much of our code would we have to change for this migration? 
What is it that HDInsight offers that EMR doesn't?

I have tried searching on the net for answers but haven't found any clear ones yet.

Thanks,
Gautam

Comment: If your product will be a Big Data product, why use .net? There is a very good reason all the big tech companies like Google, Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, Yahoo, etc, all high frequency banking, and practically all supercomputers do NOT use .net. And btw hdinsight is indeed way way behind aws.

Comment: Thanks for your input. We had evaluated Java vs .Net, however with our current set of constraints for the Minimally Viable Product, .Net is suiting us better.

Comment: There are a lot more languages than just java, what about Scala, ruby, python etc. If you use Scala you'll find u can create an MVP 10x faster becuase you only need to write 1 tenth of the code.

Comment: Writing .NET code may turn out way way easier coupled with no Boilerplate code to take care of. To be able to write scala code to do stuff with 1/10th of that code, one would have to spend months to grapple with and understand the language.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come upon the same situation except my software stack consists of Python and the possibility of JVM based languages.

Since it sounds like you are leaning towards using the .NET Framework, Azure HDInsight may be a good choice for you. If you look into HDInsight's docs, it is clear that the underlying OS is Windows. As such, engineering your application around HDInsight with your .NET requirement seems logical.